# YUI jQuery calling function on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yui

is there any one who is familiar with YUI jQuery frame work ?? i need very little help

please take the look at below code
It works perfect but the inputClick() is called when i press any button left or right but i dont want button, i want to call function when page loads means automatically 
please help me some one.

in short I want to call inputclick(e){......} automatically when page load

i heard about domready function which is same like JQuery's document.ready function
so how should i call inputClick(e)??

please take look at this ::

```
<section id="btns">
       <p>
            <input type="button" value="Left">
            <input type="button" value="Right">

    </p>
</selection>

<script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.5.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#btns').addEventListener("click", inputClick, false);

    function inputClick(e){
        var a = e.target.value;
       window.alert(a); // displays Left or Right  button value

    }

</script>
```

i tried inputClick(Left); and  inputClick(Roght); but do nothing :(

What i need is when page load ::

```
rnd = random(2);
switch(rnd)
case 1:
inputClick(Left);

case 2:
inputClick(Right);
```

i DONT want button or eventlistener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/Rh7Ju/1/

Know that anything in the YUI().use() will execute when the DOM is ready.

```
YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
    function inputClick(button_value) {
        alert(button_value);
    }
    // called when the buttons are clicked
    Y.one('#btns').on('click', function (e) {
        inputClick(e.target.get('value'));        
    }, 'input');

    inputClick('Right'); // called when the dom is ready.
});
```

After I looked at your question again, is seems like you are trying to randomly select a button and alert its value. So, maybe this is more what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/Rh7Ju/2/

Anyway, happy coding.

Comment: yep right, i did same :)

YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
      Y.on("domready", function(){
   //alert("works");
   startMyFunction();
 
      }); 
   
  
});